# Access SQL query to mailmerge

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

How can I transform this table from this

```
id name
1  sam
2  nick
3  ali
4  farah
5  josef
6  fadi
```

to

```
id1   name1   id2   name2   id3   name3   id4  name4
1     sam     2     nick    3     ali      4   farah
5     josef   6     fadi
```

the reason i need this is i have a database and i need to do a mail merge using word and I want to print every 4 rows on one page, MS word can only print one row per page, so using an SQL query I want one row to represent 4 rows

thanks in advance

Ali

Comment: i can't find out how to format it, please help :(

Comment: Press on the orange box with the white question mark over the edit area, at the top right, for formatting instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a query for this in Access. Word has a merge field called `<<Next Record>>` which forces moving to the next record. If you look at how label documents are created using the Mail Merge Wizard, you'll see that's how it's done.

**Updated - Doing this in SQL**

The columns in simple `SELECT` statements are derived from the columns from the underlying table/query (or from expressions). If you want to define columns based on the **data**, you need to use a crosstab query.

First create a query with a running count for each person (say your table is called `People`), and calculate the row and column position from the running count:

```
SELECT People.id, Count(*)-1 AS RunningCount, int(RunningCount/4) AS RowNumber, RunningCount Mod 4 AS ColumnNumber
FROM People 
LEFT JOIN People AS People_1 ON People.id >= People_1.id
GROUP BY People.id;
```

(You won't be able to view this in the Query Designer, because the `JOIN` isn't comparing with `=` but with `>=`.)

This query returns the following results:

```
id  Rank  RowNumber  ColumnNumber
1   0     0          0
2   1     0          1
3   2     0          2
4   3     0          3
5   4     1          0
6   5     1          1
```

Assuming this query is saved as `Positions`, the following query will return the results:

```
TRANSFORM First(Item) AS FirstOfItem
SELECT RowNumber
FROM (
    SELECT ID AS Item, RowNumber, "id" &( ColumnNumber + 1) AS ColumnHeading
    FROM Positions

    UNION ALL SELECT Name, RowNumber, "name" & (ColumnNumber +1)
    FROM Positions
    INNER JOIN People ON Positions.id = People.id
) AS AllValues
GROUP BY AllValues.RowNumber
PIVOT AllValues.ColumnHeading In ("id1","name1","id2","name2","id3","name3","id4","name4");
```

The `UNION` is there so each record in the `People` table will have two columns - one with the `id`, and one with the `name`.

The `PIVOT` clause forces the columns to the specified order, and not in alphabetical order (e.g. `id1`, `id2` ... `name1`, `name2`...)

Comment: I just tried your suggestion,it works thank you,
can you also show me how to do it in SQL, 
thanks :)

Comment: one last thing, if it's possible can i kindly ask you to also provide me the solution in PostgreSQL ? it doesn't have the transform/crosstab but there must be a way around it

thanks a lot for the mailmerge solution and the access sql solution :)

Comment: I've never used PostgreSQL, but look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html) at the `crosstab` table function.